# Binary change of basis in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, binary, linear-algebra, bitwise-operators

I'm implementing a decoding method from an interface control document, and it requires a change of basis in binary - which is a first for me. The change of basis is as follows (*z* is what i have, the matrix is the transformation, and *u* is what I need):

[image]

and it states:

[image]

What I've tried is to multiply the *z_n* vector by each column of the transformation matrix (using and AND operator) and add the results (with an XOR operator), like this:

```
u = (z & base[0])^(z & base[1])^(z & base[2])^(z & base[3])^(z & base[4])^(z & base[5])^(z & base[6])^(z & base[7]);
```

where *z* is the binary number to be transformed (e.g. 10100101, or its representation as 8-bit int) and base are the columns of the transformation matrix represented as integers:

```
uint8_t base[8] = {155, 221, 62, 28, 55, 179, 96, 148};
```

But the results don't match with what it was supposed to be. Am I implementing this change of basis correctly?

**Edit**

I have the inverse transformation as well. If the implementation is correct, I should be able to transform a byte, and then transform it back to the original state. In my implementation, the back transformation yields a different result:

[image]

Problem solved. Here's the verification code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Base change*/
uint8_t const matrix[] = { 0xC5, 0x42, 0x2E, 0xFD, 0xF0, 0x79, 0xAC, 0xCC }; // the rows
uint8_t const matrixinv[] = {0x8D, 0xEF, 0xEC, 0x86, 0xFA, 0x99, 0xAF, 0x7B}; // the rows

uint8_t const z = 0x64;
uint8_t u, z2;


void main(){

    printf("initial value: %d ", z);
    u = 0;
    if (z & 0x80) u ^= matrix[0];
    if (z & 0x40) u ^= matrix[1];
    if (z & 0x20) u ^= matrix[2];
    if (z & 0x10) u ^= matrix[3];
    if (z & 0x08) u ^= matrix[4];
    if (z & 0x04) u ^= matrix[5];
    if (z & 0x02) u ^= matrix[6];
    if (z & 0x01) u ^= matrix[7];

    printf(" - forward result: %d ",u);

    z2 = u;
    u = 0;
    if (z2 & 0x80) u ^= matrixinv[0];
    if (z2 & 0x40) u ^= matrixinv[1];
    if (z2 & 0x20) u ^= matrixinv[2];
    if (z2 & 0x10) u ^= matrixinv[3];
    if (z2 & 0x08) u ^= matrixinv[4];
    if (z2 & 0x04) u ^= matrixinv[5];
    if (z2 & 0x02) u ^= matrixinv[6];
    if (z2 & 0x01) u ^= matrixinv[7];

    printf("back result: %d ",u);
    getchar();
}

initial value: 100  - forward result: 21 back result: 100
```

Comment: What is a "basis"?

Comment: It has not much to do with binary *per se*. It's just a set of orthogonal vectors.

Comment: From wikipedia: In linear algebra, a basis for a vector space is a linearly independent set spanning the vector space. A basis for a vector space of dimension n is a set of n vectors, called basis vectors, with the property that every vector in the space can be expressed as a unique linear combination of the basis vectors.

Basically, this matrix transforms one system into another. But I don't know how to handle it in the binary/bitwise realm

Comment: the simplest is to apply plain brute force matrix multiplication. If you implement a basis transformation for first time, this is the way to go. Even for something more sophisticated I would always use the matrix-vector multiplication as reference

Comment: The constants are wrong. The values in the matrix do not match the values shown for `base`. For example, we would expect `base[0]`, which is initialized to 155 (10011011 in binary) corresponds to the first column in the displayed matrix (01111111 or 11111110, depending on which way it is written), but it does not. The bit pattern for 155 does not appear in any row or column, read in either direction, so it is not a correct value for the matrix shown.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I actually put the inverse basis change. I edited with the correct one and double checked the values.

Comment: Show sample inputs, expected outputs, and observed outputs.

Comment: Eric, this is part of a much larger procedure. I don't have reference intermediate values since the inputs are available online and the end result, after this larger procedure, is transmitted by a satellite. I was able to verify with MATLAB all the other portions of the code, with the exception of this one. The problem is in the way I'm doing this change of basis, but can test only this procedure in the larger software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your language supports vectorized two-operand XOR.  It doesn't support horizontal XOR (parity calculation).  So we'll structure our operations accordingly.

Assuming

```
uint8_t const matrix[] = { 0xC5, 0x42, 0x2E, 0xFD, 0xF0, 0x79, 0xAC, 0xCC }; // the rows
uint8_t const z;
uint8_t u;
```

Your result is going to be

```
u = 0;
if (z & 0x80) u ^= matrix[0];
if (z & 0x40) u ^= matrix[1];
if (z & 0x20) u ^= matrix[2];
// etc following the pattern
// if ((z << i) & 0x80) u ^= matrix[i];
```

Note that I've assumed that the reversal of bit order between input and output is a mistake.  If it's correct, you may need to mirror all the contents of `matrix`.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! It worked. I added the verification code snippet in the original post.

Comment: @Marco: Notice that the round-trip "verification" may pass even if we have reversed the bit order, because two reversals cancel.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. In this particular implementation I'm working, z is passed bit by bit, so I can reverse it before multiplying by the matrix. I just wanted to check how the bitwise operation is performed in this situation. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also reverse `z` by pairing `matrix[0]` with `z & 0x01` and `matrix[7]` with `z & 0x80`